# VP230 CAN Bus Transceiver

Tags: serial, can-bus

How does one read can packets from a VP230 Can Bus transceiver? I also have a MCP2515 which I've gotten to work, but the VP230 is a lot smaller.

I haven't been able to find any information about actually implementing the VP230, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome. You are talking two compatible CAN parts but they have different functions. The VP230 is the CAN bus bidirectional interface. This converts the signals on the CAN bus to logic signals your CAN controller can use. The MPC2515 is a CAN controller chip that talks to your microprocessor and the bus transceiver. The MCP2515 has only logic signals and is not compatible with the CAN bus. Together they make a good CAN bus interface. Both parts are 3V3 compatible.

Comment: So may I ask, when I connect my VP230 to my arduino, and read serial from it, what data am I reading

Comment: I am assuming it is connected to the MCP2515 and that is converting the CAN data. However I do not know. It depends on what you have it hooked up to. 
Connecting the VP230 to serial will probably just give you garbage, the format it will receive is not compatible with async serial.  You need the  MCP2515 or similar part to convert the data. CAN has a lot of control bits in its transmission that will not make sense unless you use a CAN controller chip.  You can have the Arduino convert that to serial if you want. Look at the send.ino and receive.ino in the Cory Fowler library.